# Improving models for a Django quiz

Tags: python, mvc, django, quiz

I'm working on a little django quiz taking app. Currently I'm making it's models. So far I've got `Quiz`, `Question`, `Answer`, and `Response` designed as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from npage.mixins import TranslatedModelMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Quiz(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False,)

    # show_feedback = models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=True,help_text="Correct answer is shown after question.",)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Quiz"
        verbose_name_plural = "Quizzes"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model, TranslatedModelMixin):

    quiz = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, blank=True, )

    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, help_text="Enter the question text that you want displayed",verbose_name='Question',)
    es_content = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, help_text="Enter the question text that you want displayed",verbose_name='Question',)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TYPES, default='radio')
    is_scoreable = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="Will the answer to this question be scored?")

    # idea
    # tags = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, help_text="Enter some text to help you find this question to add it to quizzes later on.",verbose_name='Question',)

    feedback = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,help_text="Explanation to be shown after the question has been answered.",verbose_name='Explanation',)
    es_feedback = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,help_text="Explanation to be shown after the question has been answered.",verbose_name='Explanation',)

    TYPES = (
        ('radio', 'radio'),
        ('checkbox', 'checkbox'),
        ('text', 'text'),
    )

    language_code = 'en'
    translated_fields = ['content', 'feedback']


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Question"
        verbose_name_plural = "Questions"
        #ordering = ['category']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content

class Answer(models.Model, TranslatedModelMixin):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, help_text="Enter the answer text that you want displayed",)
    es_content = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, help_text="Enter the answer text that you want displayed",)

    correct = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False,help_text="Is this a correct answer?")

    language_code = 'en'
    translated_fields = ['content']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content

class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    # Could have either an FK to an answer OR some free response text.
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
    free_response = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.answer:
            return self.answer
        else:
            return free_response
```

I am especially concerned with the elegance of my `Response` model. The idea here is a question might be multiple choice (radio group or checkbox group) OR free response (text) so a `response` could either be a foreign key to an `answer` (which may or may not be correct) OR just some plain text (probably not both). Is this a good design? What can I do to improve my models

Comment: Thank you for using my quiz app, I hope that it is helpful. I have added few changes which you might find useful: https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz/

Answer (score 2):

You could have an abstract superclass `Response` which has concrete derived classes of `multipleChoiceResponse` and `freeResponse`. Then you can have a method such as `checkResponse` which is different for each type of respones.

EDIT:

How about this:

```
from django.db import models

class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class freeResponse(Response):
    free_response = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)

class multipleChoiceResponse(Response) #does not handle multi-select (tickbox) cases
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
```

Comment: Will this work with Django models?

Comment: You can do inheritance with Django models. The example above does not handle the multi-select (tickbox) case, but it handles the radio-button case. You could add a method called checkResponse() which could do the checking for you. Also there might be a boolean in the superclass `correct = True`?